# How to connect GKE to an AWS RDS instance?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-rds, google-kubernetes-engine

What's the best/easier way to connect an AWS RDS instance to my kubernetes cluster running on gcloud?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems have you experienced? For tips on asking a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Likely the only way there is, is using their `public availability` option upon creating the instance. That really is just fine. You will get a DNS hostname that also powers their loadbalancing feature.

Note, their are similar question for connection within AWS, which report DNS problems, that do not apply in your case Ref: [Accessing Postgres RDS from Kubernetes cluster in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277075/accessing-postgres-rds-from-kubernetes-cluster-in-aws)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is: Add a label for some of your nodes with `kubectl label nodes` in order to have control over their public IP addresses, they are ephemeral so I think you will want to reserve a static IP for those nodes you choose.

Each virtual machine is named with its corresponding node's name, so you can use the same name you used in the previous `kubectl label nodes` command.

Now all you have to do is, add each IP to the security group that corresponds to your RDS instance.